# How can I set the timer start time text box value in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, button, timer, textbox

I am creating the timer. I have two windows Mainwindow and Settings. The *Mainwindow* has two buttons. **StartStopBtn** and **ShowSettingsWindow**.
*Settings* has a **SetTimeBtn** and **timerTxb**.

***MainWindow.xaml***
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZHKt.png)

***I declared the timer start time as int, how can I get the value in the text box instead of int start = 10?***

***MainWindow.xaml.cs***

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    DispatcherTimer timer;
    public Settings settings;
    public int start = 10;
    // Here I want to assign settings.timerTxb.Text value to a variable instead of int start = 10;
    int start =Convert.ToInt32(settings.timerTxb.Text); // This code is not working

    public MainWindow()
    {            

        InitializeComponent();
        timer = new DispatcherTimer();            
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        start--;            
        StartStopBtn.Content = start;          
    }

    private void StartStopBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        
        if (timer.IsEnabled == false)
        {
            timer.Start();
            StartStopBtn.Content = start;
        }
        else
        {
            timer.Stop();
            StartStopBtn.Content = start;
        }
    }

    private void showWindow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        settings = new Settings();
        settings.Show();
    }        
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrRcx.gif)

***Settings.xaml***
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVgAu.png)

I declared the timer start time in this program as an int type. But I need to enter the timer start time in the text field. The **StartStopBtn** button in the Mainwindow should show the timer time. This button must be both start (resume) and stop.
**I declared the timer start time as int, how can I get the value in the text box instead of int start = 10?**

Comment: "I declared the timer start time in this program as an int type. But I need to enter the timer start time in the text field."     The text field? Which one?  And what does **int type** have to do with a text field?    After reading the question it's pretty unclear what your real problem is.

Comment: Sorry, I have changed it.

Comment: How can I use textbox value in another class field as int start=10; Could you help me, please? I didn't do this for 3 days.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: You could use application settings to store your value, first you need to add a condition to check that textbox input is only numeric, Add a PreviewTextInput event to your TextBox on Settings page.

C#:

```
    private void timerTxb_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex InputChecker = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[^0-9]+");
        e.Handled = InputChecker.IsMatch(e.Text);
    }
```

XAML:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="LightGray">
    <Label Content="Set Timer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"></Label>
    <TextBox x:Name="timerTxb" Width="Auto" MinWidth="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" PreviewTextInput="timerTxb_PreviewTextInput"/>
    <Button x:Name="SetTimeBtn" Content="Save and Close" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="SetTimeBtn_Click"></Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Step 2: Now create app setting, this is where you can store the value from the TextBox.
Go to Project\[App's name] Properties.

[image: Project Settings 1]

Name your setting "TimerStart", make sure it's an int type and set it's value to 10.

[image: Project Settings 2]

Step 3: After you have your setting ready it's time to set it's value, add this code to your SetTimeBtn click event:

```
    private void SetTimeBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.TimerStart = Int32.Parse(timerTxb.Text);
        this.Close();
    }
```

Step 4: That's all for the settings page, now this is the code I put in MainWindow.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    }

    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    private int start = new int();
    private int CheckPosition = 0;
    private bool ButtonStateCheck = false;

    private void StartStopBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {          
        if (ButtonStateCheck == false)
        {
            if (CheckPosition == 0)
            {
                start = Properties.Settings.Default.TimerStart;
            }
            else if (CheckPosition != 0)
            {
                start = CheckPosition;
            }
            timer.Start();
            ButtonStateCheck = true;
        }
        else if (ButtonStateCheck == true)
        {
            CheckPosition = start;
            ButtonStateCheck = false;
            timer.Stop();
        }
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (start > 0)
        {
            start--;
            StartStopBtn.Content = start;
        }
        else if (start <= 0)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            CheckPosition = 0;
            ButtonStateCheck= false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Dark Templar, but in this code, the StartStopBtn button starts only from the beginning, that is, from the number entered in the textbox. StartStopBtn was supposed to be both starts (resume) and stops (Pause).

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrRcx.gif  I wanted to do the same

Comment: Please. Could you help me ?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood, I updated the codes to support resume\pause behavior.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your expertise. Best of good luck :)